# Infinitely loop a jquery function until a stop button is clicked? Open/Close Webpage Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty straightforward here. I want to open and close a webpage window in a loop ( infinitely ) until the loop is broken.

Here is my code. I managed to get the window to open and close with two separate buttons, but failed to arrange the functions in a loop.

Also, there might need to be a delay between opening and closing the window. Split second delay where I noted the code //add delay here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="stop">
    <button>Stop</button>
</div>

<script>
    var myWindow;
    function openWin() {
        myWindow = window.open("https://losangeles.craigslist.org/lac/bts/6159876722.html", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
    }

    function closeWin() {
        myWindow.close();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myWindow;,
        delay = .2; //seconds

        function loop ( delay ) {
            openWin()
            //add delay here?

            closeWin()
        }

        loop( delay );

        $("button").on("click", function() {
            $text.stop(true, false);
        })
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
<title>Cart</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 



<body>

<div class="stop">
<button>Stop</button>
</div>

<script>


var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("https://losangeles.craigslist.org/lac/bts/6159876722.html", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();

}

     $(document).ready(function() {
    var myWindow;,
    setInterval(function(){ openWin(); }, 200);
    setInterval(function(){ closeWin(); }, 400);//the 


    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $text.stop(true, false);
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be better:
[PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/LLYyqR)

```
var myWindow;
var interval;
    function openWin() {
       myWindow = window.open("https://losangeles.craigslist.org/lac/bts/6159876722.html", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
    }

    function closeWin() {
        myWindow.close();
    }

    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
        var myWindow;
        var delay = .2; //seconds
        var delayBeforeClose = .3;


        function loop ( delay ) {
            openWin()
            //add delay here?

            setTimeout(closeWin,delayBeforeClose*1000)
        }

        interval = setInterval(loop,(delay+delayBeforeClose)*1000)

        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click',()=>{
          clearInterval(interval)
        })

    });
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var myWindow;//duplicate declartion of variable
    setInterval(function(){ openWin(); }, 200);
    setInterval(function(){ closeWin(); }, 400);//the 


    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $text.stop(true, false);
    })
});
```

Comment: I updated my question using what you posted. I didn't work where I used it.